# UniqueConstraint error message handling in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How do I attach a message to `uniqueConstraints` below in the entity itself? Second query below will generate `An exception occurred while executing....SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry...`. Instead of this unfriendly message how can I print "You request whatever whatever ..."?

**SQL 1-** `INSERT INTO cars (model, brands_id) VALUES ('bmw', '5')`

**SQL 2-** `INSERT INTO cars (model, brands_id) VALUES ('bmw', '5')`

**Note:** I find Symfony documentation poor in general and the most seem to be short-cut. If you're looking for a solution and if someone knows the answer then you're luck if not you're ....

**ENTITY**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="cars", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"model", "brands_id"})})
 */
class Cars
{
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
try
{
    $submission = $form->getData();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $cars = new Cars();
    $cars->setModel($submission->getModel());
    $cars->setBrands($submission->getBrands());

    $em->persist($cars);
    $em->flush();

    .......
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    ......
}
```

**FORM TYPE**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->setAction($options['action'])
        ->setMethod('POST')

        ->add('brands', 'entity',
            array(
                'class' => 'CarBrandBundle:Brands',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'empty_value' => '',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repo)
                                    {
                                        return $repo->createQueryBuilder('b')->orderBy('b.name', 'ASC');
                                    }
            ))

        ->add('model', 'text', array('label' => 'Model'))
        ->add('button', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'))
    ;
}
```

Comment: Will this INSERT come after a form submission?

Comment: Yes it is coming from form type.

Comment: I've added form type as reference above.

Comment: `uniqueConstraints` is just a Doctrine annotation which will use it to create the right tables in the database. It's just for integrity and perfomance. You need to use `validation` to generate errors and display error messages. Take a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html).

Comment: @DonCallisto A custom validator isn't needed. The Symonfy2 standard edition provides a constraint for this: `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity`.

Comment: I'm using `@UniqueEntity(fields={"model","brands",}, message="Duplicated entry.")` so this is what I'll use from now on. Thank you very much

Comment: Perfect! I hardly use annotations, so I didn't know the exact implementation. Glad it's solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `validation.yml` file in your `src/Car/BrandBundle/Resources/config` folder.

The contents should be similar to this:

```
CAR\BrandBundle\Entity\Cars:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [model, brands_id]
            message: "your_message_here"
```

You could also use annotations to use validation constraints.

For more info read [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html).

Comment: I'll remember this as an example for second option so thank you for that. I've added solution above in comment. +1 and I'm accepting your solution as well.